# Android Studio Network Profiler cannot see JSON response body

Tags: android-studio

I've upgraded to Android Studio 3.0 rc1.  I'm trying to use the Network Profiler.  I am unable to see any JSON in the response body

[image]

On the documentation page, the response preview section shows an image.  Is Android Studio Network Profiler capable of showing JSON?  Or is it just to preview images?  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and tracked it down to my proguard configuration. It appears that the profiler uses reflection to call some of the okhttp3 methods, but these were stripped by the proguard.

Adding the following line to my proguard rules solved the problem for me:

```
-keep class okhttp3.Headers { *; }
```

Comment: how can this be related to proguard? It's an AndroidStudio tool which is mostly run on your debug build. And usually you don't use proguard in your debug builds.

Comment: Unless you do, because of method count. This particular approach solved the problem for me, but I cannot exclude it has also other causes and therefore multiple different solutions.

Comment: This worked for me thanks. Our debug builds run proguard and I got this in the log cat ```Could not track an OkHttp3 request due to a missing method, which could happen if your project uses proguard to remove unused code
    java```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and as far as I know it doesn't work with network libraries like retrofit. For me a reason to use OkHttp directly next time

UPDATE: problem seems to be fixed. In my retrofit based projects the profiler now works correctly.

Comment: this is totally wrong, retrofit uses okhttp as it's engine so the problem is not there

Comment: True, I misinterpreted "Currently, the Network Profiler supports only the HttpURLConnection and OkHttp libraries for network connections"